# How to find dead code in XSLT legacy codebase

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, legacy, basex

I’ve started with a [BaseX v9 XQuery](https://gitlab.com/ms152718212/reengxslt/blob/8aa88a26b1f577371be56cd6575686d237383031/ReengHelper/ReengHelper.xqy) script that helps me to analyze a XSLT legacy codebase. There are ~100 XSL v1.0 files and over the years there is a little bit of a mess.

The code requires a cleanup. A first step is to find unused code (templates, variables etc.).

My question is about finding match templates that are no longer used:

```
 <xsl:template match="blabla">...</xsl:template>
```

In general, what is the best way to find match templates (with or with no mode attribute) that will never be executed?

Comment: There is no "best" way but there are some transformations that can be performed to analyze the code-base and find candidates for exclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons a template rule might never be executed: either there is another template rule that will always be chosen in preference, or there is NO conceivable source document with a node that matches its pattern. It's not really practical to detect either of these situations by static analysis of the stylesheet. Your best bet is to do some code coverage analysis dynamically, using a representative sample of source documents (and other input conditions such as values of stylesheet parameters).

It's worth googling for "code coverage XSLT" though it will give you more questions than answers. XSpec does code coverage, but only if you have a comprehensive set of XSpec tests, which seems unlikely. Saxon has a facility (-TP:profile.html) that outputs how often each template rule has executed, but sadly, it omits those for which the count is zero. It wouldn't be too hard to combine this data with some source code analysis to find the template rules that don't appear in the list (and also, to combine the outputs from multiple runs with different source documents.)

An alternative to actually executing the stylesheet against many source documents would be to extract the match patterns into a synthetic stylesheet that tests every input node against every match pattern. You could output an element for every match, then post-process the output to look for patterns missing from the output:

First:

```
<xsl:template match="... a sample pattern... ">
  <match id="654321"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
(repeated for each pattern in the original stylesheet)
```

Then for the analysis:

```
<xsl:variable name="data" select="."/>
<xsl:key name="k" match="match" use="@id"/>
<xsl:for-each select="1 to max(//match/@id)[not(key('k', ., $data))]">
  No matches for pattern id="{.}"
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, this will give you false "no matches" results for template rules that could be fired by an `xsl:apply-imports` or `xsl:next-match` instruction, or for nodes that match more than one template rule (perhaps in different modes). I'm sure the idea could be refined.

Comment: There are examples of useful static analysis that is simple to code and execute and can provide results that help us find and eliminate dead XSLT code.

Comment: There may be a few such examples but I suspect most dead template rules occur simply because the XML constructs that they match have fallen out of use.

Comment: @MichaelKay For me _executing the stylesheet against many source documents_ (in our case few but large sources) is a good probabilistic approach. It helps to find candidates of rules that are no longer used. I can write a [XQuery](http://basex.org/basex/xquery/) script for instrumenting the code and makes profiling easy. No other tool support is needed. _extract the match patterns into a synthetic stylesheet_ is more complicated because in our case temporary xml trees with unknown schema are frequently used [...], and to find out for what type of nodes the rules are intended for is hard.

Comment: Let us warn the reader that the second approach will not give us representative results if the set of stylesheets that is being investigated implements multi-pass processing. To be more precise, a template that matches a node in an intermediate pass of processing, but not any node from the raw input, will be falsely marked as "no-matches"

Answer (score 0):

> The code requires a cleanup. A first step is to find unused code
>   (templates, variables etc.).
>
> My question is about finding match templates that are no longer used:

**The good news is** that things are not so theoretical (and near hopeless) as I see them in the other answer. A lot of useful information can be obtained with static analysis alone.

Recently I did something similar. This simple transformation found out that in the 530 .xsl or .xslt files, 180 were "Main" (not imported or included by any other stylesheet).

Then looking at the "Main" stylesheets one by one and determining if this is ever used as a primary (standalone) transformation, allows to exclude a lot of such XSLT files.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vBaseFileUrl" select="'file:///C:/TheDirectoryPathToTheXSLTCode'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vStyleSheets" select=
 "collection(concat($vBaseFileUrl, '?select=*.xsl;recurse=yes'))
 |
  collection(concat($vBaseFileUrl, '?select=*.xslt;recurse=yes'))"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    Number of *.xsl | *.xslt stylesheets: <xsl:value-of select="count($vStyleSheets)"/>

    Document URIs:
    <xsl:variable name="vdocURIs" select="$vStyleSheets/document-uri(.)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$vdocURIs" separator="&#xA;"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vDistinctFilenames" select=
    "distinct-values($vStyleSheets/tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()])"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;','&#xA;',
                          'Distinctly named stylesheets: ', count($vDistinctFilenames)"/>

<xsl:variable name="vMainFilenames" select=
"$vDistinctFilenames
    [not(. = $vStyleSheets/*/(xsl:import | xsl:include)/tokenize(@href, '/')[last()])]"/>

<xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;','&#xA;','Main filenames: ', count($vMainFilenames)"/>

<xsl:variable name="vMainStylesheets" select=
"$vStyleSheets[tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()] = $vMainFilenames]
"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;','&#xA;','Main stylesheets: ', count($vMainStylesheets)"/>

==========================================
    Document URIs grouped by name: <xsl:text/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$vdocURIs" group-by="tokenize(., '/')[last()]">
      <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vStylesheetFilename" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vImportedOrIncluded" select=
      "$vStyleSheets[/*/(xsl:import | xsl:include)[tokenize(@href, '/')[last()] 
                     eq $vStylesheetFilename]][1]"/>

      <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;', '&#xA;', 
                            $vStylesheetFilename, 
                            if(empty($vImportedOrIncluded)) then ' Main ' else (), ':'"/>
==========================================
<xsl:text/>

      <xsl:variable name="vUrisInGroup" as="xs:string*">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
          <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:for-each select="$vUrisInGroup">
        <xsl:value-of select=
           "substring-after(., substring-before(., 'nameOfRootDir')), '&#xA;'"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

On the level of matching templates:

Let's have:

```
<xsl:template match="possiblySomepath/someName[PossiblySomePredicate]/possibleTailPath">
```

We analyze the set of possible source XML documents and determine that these never contain an element named "someName" -- or in a better scenario we have available an  XML Schema of the source and from it we see that no element named "someName" is contained in the document(s). Then we can safely remove that template.

As for "Main" stylesheets, after we have excluded the obvious of these, in a similar way we can investigate and find **named** templates for which there is no matching `<xsl:call-template>` instruction -- and get rid of all these.

The code will be something like this:

```
==========================================
    <xsl:variable name="vTemplateNamesDistinct" 
      select="distinct-values($vStyleSheets/*/xsl:template/@name)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "'&#xA;','&#xA;','Distinct template names: ', count($vTemplateNamesDistinct)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vnamedTemplatesNeverCalled" select=
   "distinct-values($vStyleSheets/*/xsl:template/@name
                     [not(. = $vStyleSheets//xsl:call-template/@name)])"/>
    <xsl:value-of select=
       "'&#xA;','&#xA;','Template names never called: ', count($vnamedTemplatesNeverCalled)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$vnamedTemplatesNeverCalled" separator="&#xA;"/>
==========================================
```

In my case there were around 400 named templates. Of these more than 40 named templates were not called.

Comment: thank you for sharing ideas and code. I guess your code does something in a way similar to my XQuery scripts that i linked. But i am in the process of understanding :) and will return later.

Comment: @MarkusSchmid The best way to understand what this transformation does (and I strongly recommend it) is to run it and just look at the results -- these are quite self-explanatory.

Comment: Does it run under open source Saxon-HE 9? (Currently i'm on a XSLT/XPath v1.0 stack)

Comment: Should run -- I am running it with an old version -- Saxon 9.1 -- not using any XSLT 3.0 features -- only 2.0